# How to build a UL LI as card with complex layout (example included)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a "card" within a `ul li` list. This cards should be responsive. Therefore my core idea was to use `CSS Flexbox`. I have started a pen at codepen.io but struggling now for days to achieve this. Why cant i align easily these divs with flexbox?

This is how it should look like:
[image]

This is the pen:
https://codepen.io/bogazci/pen/WNayNXb?editors=1100

HTML

```
<ul class="packs-list">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="pack">
      <div class="pack-sku">B01-102 102<br>ordered on 14th may 23</div>
      <div class="pack-card">
        <h2 class="pack-title">Customer Engagement</h2>
        <div class="pack-description">This is the descriptin for the.</div>
        <div class="pack-information">This item contains <b>2123</b> elements in <b>231</b> containers.</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.pack-sku {
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
} 

.pack-card {
  background-color: brown;
} 

.pack {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
} 

.packs-list {
  background-color: yellow;
} 

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.pack-card {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically an `ul` element can only contain `li` elements, while a `li` can contain anything. I corrected the HTML to reflect that.

It is not clear what you were aiming for using *Flexbox Layout* like you did, so I recreated your CSS starting from scratch.

The CSS is commented, so I will not repeat it here, but the trick with *Flexbox Layout* is to distinguish between the various column and row parent containers and which child items should be allowed/forced to grow/shrink or not.

As a bonus I added a few 'responsiveness' solutions and some hover effects you can fiddle with: `body { font-size }`, `@media` and `pack:hover`/`pack:hover>a`.

A [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/JjmZYWO) you can fork...

```css
/* makes padding+border part of total element size */
* { box-sizing: border-box }

:root {
    /* Define a few values for general use */
    --pad: 0.5rem; /* generic padding */
    --bd : 3px;    /* border size */
}

body {
    margin: 0; /* Remove HTML default spacing */

    padding: calc(2 * var(--pad));
    font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem); /* Responsive font */

    background-color: #efefef;
}

.list {
    /* Remove HTML defaults */
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

/******************/
/* Flexbox Layout */
/******************/
/* Flexbox parent containers */
.list, .pack>a, .pack-card { display: flex }
.list, .pack>a             { flex-flow: row wrap }
.pack-card                 { flex-flow: column wrap; justify-content: space-between }
.list                      { justify-content: center }

/* Flexbox child items */
.pack-sku, .pack-card,
.pack-description          { flex: 1 } /* allow to stretch to fill parent */

/* Flexbox spacing */
.list                      { gap: calc(2 * var(--pad)) }
.pack>a, .pack-card        { gap: var(--pad) }

/**********************/
/* Sizing and Styling */
/**********************/
/* All classes containing ... */
[class*="pack"] { padding: var(--pad) }

.pack {
/*    max-width: min(24rem, 100%); /* toy with this */

    background-color: White;
    border: var(--bd) solid #aaa;
    color: #444;
}
.pack:hover {
    border-color: Black;
    color: Black;
}

.pack>a {
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    text-decoration-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: currentColor;
}
.pack:hover>a {
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    text-decoration-color: Black;
}

.pack-sku {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: var(--bd) solid #c4590f;
}

/* Make vertical textbox when space allows */
@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
    .pack-sku {
        flex: 0; /* disable fill parent size */

        /* Rotate writing direction and element */
        -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        transform: rotate(180deg);

        text-align: right;
    }
}

.pack-card        { border: var(--bd) solid #2c74b4 }
.pack-title       { border: var(--bd) solid #febf01; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold }
.pack-description { border: var(--bd) solid #6fac45 }
.pack-information { border: var(--bd) solid #fe0000 }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="pack">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="pack-sku">B01-102 102<br>ordered on 14th may 23</div>
            <div class="pack-card">
                <div class="pack-title">Customer Engagement</div>
                <div class="pack-description">This is the description for the...</div>
                <div class="pack-information">This item contains <b>2123</b> elements in <b>231</b> containers.</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pack">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="pack-sku">B01-102 102<br>ordered on 14th may 23</div>
            <div class="pack-card">
                <div class="pack-title">Customer Engagement</div>
                <div class="pack-description">This is the description for the...</div>
                <div class="pack-information">This item contains <b>2123</b> elements in <b>231</b> containers.</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="pack">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="pack-sku">B01-102 102<br>ordered on 14th may 23</div>
            <div class="pack-card">
                <div class="pack-title">Customer Engagement</div>
                <div class="pack-description">This is the description for the...</div>
                <div class="pack-information">This item contains <b>2123</b> elements in <b>231</b> containers.</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @STORM, I modified the Codepen to incorporate a QR-code with a link to the pen.

Answer (score 0):

still align based on the `height` of that element

You can use `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` and negative `margin`

**Example** :

```
.pack-sku{
  ...
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1
  ...
}
.pack-card {
  background-color: brown;
  margin: -150px; /* example */
}
```

But i suggest you to use **javascript**

somthing like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="packs-list">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="pack">
      <div class="pack-sku">
        <!-- NEW -->
        <span>B01-102 102<br>ordered on 14th may 23</span>
      </div>
      <div class="pack-card">
        <h2 class="pack-title">Customer Engagement</h2>
        <div class="pack-description">This is the descriptin for the.</div>
        <div class="pack-information">This item contains <b>2123</b> elements in <b>231</b> containers.</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.pack-sku {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.pack-sku > span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.querySelector('.pack-sku').style.width = document.querySelector('.pack-sku span').offsetHeight + 'px';

document.querySelector('.pack-sku').style.height = document.querySelector('.pack-sku span').offsetWidth + 'px';
```